# Configuring a Object Data Source to a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am new to programming and was woundering if anyone can help me. I am trying to create a form using the data from a website. I have assigned an objectDataSource to a drop down list successfully and now need to assign data to a label. Does anyone know how to assign a ObjectDataSource to a label? Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Could you please provide some code examples and go deeper into the context of a problem? Thus, we would have more details to give a better, coherent answer to your question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say assign Data To a Label.? labels are used to explain the data for example label1.Text =`'First Name`; tells the individual entering or reading data from the Textbox next to the label that this is the `First Name` of pertaining to the data that is being presented.. please be more specific as to what you would like to do with the data once retrieved from the DataSource

Answer (score -1):

In the following example you could have a SQL Data-source bound to the label text property

```
public string SqlConnection(string queryString)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = queryString;
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // This will return the first result 
                    // but there might be other
                    return reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

assign the Text property of the label

```
lblTest.Text = SqlConnection("SELECT Description FROM RbSpecials WHERE Active=1");
```

Comment: exactly, I am not sure how many labels he has. He has not given enough information for the problem and his source code. My example atleast demonstrates how to bind a data source to a label